# Indy TCP client example?

Tags: indy, c++builder-xe5

Is there any sample code for Indy 10 sockets in C++Builder?

The two sample links on the [Indy Demos page](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/demos/index.en.aspx) are dead links and I have been unable to find any sample code after extensive searching.

I am writing a client that will send and receive JSON messages, no complicated protocols or SSL required.

I have been able to guess based on the member functions of TIdTCPClient to write  `id1->Socket->WriteLn` to send something which gets received by the server but have not yet figured out how to receive the server's response.

Also, is there any overview documentation for Indy TCP client?  In some Delphi snippets I saw `id1.IOHandler.WriteLn` used instead but I don't see any explanation of what IOHandler is for, which one I should use, what the difference is between IOHandler.WriteLn and Socket.WriteLn, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK. I see that I went the wrong way the first time on that demo and ended up [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/files/) which only has Flashes and PDFs, instead of using the SVN link.  That demo is only in Delphi but it's better than nothing I guess.

Answer (score 3):

> The two sample links on the [Indy Demos page](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/demos/index.en.aspx) are dead links

The only dead link on that page is Ralph's `TIdTCPClient/Server with SSL` demo.  The other links work fine, including the one to `TCP/IP Delphi&Indy10 Client Server Demo`.

> I have been unable to find any sample code after extensive searching.

Then you are not searching very well, because there have been tons of examples posted in the Embarcadero and Indy forums, and even here on StackOverflow.

> I have been able to guess based on the member functions of TIdTCPClient to write  `id1->Socket->WriteLn` to send something which gets received by the server but have not yet figured out how to receive the server's response.

`TIdTCPClient` is not an asynchronous component. It reads only when you tell it to read. Assuming your `WriteLn()` is sending a request, you can call `ReadLn()` (or whatever reading method you want) immediately after `WriteLn()` exits, eg:

```
id1->Socket->WriteLn("JSON data here");
String response = id1->Socket->ReadLn();
```

If you want to read responses asynchronously, do the reading in a separate worker thread.

> Also, is there any overview documentation for Indy TCP client?

The official documentation is on Indy's website:

http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.aspx

http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html

The documentation is a bit old, especially the class reference portion, but the overviews still largely apply.

> In some Delphi snippets I saw `id1.IOHandler.WriteLn` used instead but I don't see any explanation of what IOHandler is for, which one I should use, what the difference is between IOHandler.WriteLn and Socket.WriteLn, etc.

The `Socket` property is provided for convenience. When the `IOHandler` property points at a `TIdIOHandlerSocket` object, the `Socket` property returns that same object. This avoids any need to type-cast the `IOHandler` to access any socket-specific functionality. Indy implements several `IOHandler`s other than for socket I/O, and you can write custom `IOHandler`s as well.

The `IOHandler` does all the real work. You should use the `IOHandler` property instead of the `Socket` property when accessing any IO-agnostic methods, like `WriteLn()` and `ReadLn()`.  This way, you can swap out different `IOHandler` objects at will.  This is useful, for instance, when capturing socket activity and replaying it for debugging purposes.

Comment: Does the Indy TCP client support a worker thread reading the socket while another thread is simultaneously sending on the same socket?

Comment: My searching has found you saying "there have been tons of examples posted in the Embarcadero and Indy forums, and even here on StackOverflow." but I could not find any such examples on EDN or SO. Could you link directly to them?   Also, I searched "TIdTCPClient example" on Indy Forums and the results all seem to be q/a threads , not set examples.

Comment: Your documentation links have a latest version of 10.1.5,  however in another post I saw you say that XE4 comes with 10.6 . (So I presume that XE5 has at least 10.6 also)

Comment: As I said, the documentation is a bit old, but it is the only official documentation provided. And yes, XE5 shipped with (a later revision of) 10.6.0. The current version is 10.6.2.